# Tableau SQL Error: Type double precision. " "

Tags: sql, tableau-desktop

I have custom SQL code in Tableau that is giving issues with loading. Every time I try to click 'Update Now' under edit connections, my Tableau gives me an error relating to double precision. I'm thinking it might have to do with something as small as spacing, but I've checked all the spacing unless I'm missing something. I've looked at it and I'm running out of ideas. Any help would be much appreciated :)

```
SELECT DISTINCT property_space_availability_skey,
--Property Info
property_name,
property_address_line_1,
property_city,
property_district_desc,
property_status_desc,
property_latitude, property_longitude,
floor_number, suite_number,
property_usage_type_desc,
property_usage_sub_type_desc,
property_class_type_desc,
property_market_desc,
property_sub_market_desc,
-- Space Info
available_space,
--Space Details
space_availability_status_desc,
date_on_market,
listing_desc,
total_area_of_space,
date_available,
lease_type_desc,
total_contiguous_area_of_space,
sub_divide_allowed_f,
listing_notes,
/* Industrial specs */
clear_height AS "Clear Height",
minimum_clear_height AS "Min Clear Height",
maximum_clear_height AS "Max Clear Height",
number_of_dock_doors AS "Dock Doors",
number_of_grade_level_doors AS "Grade Level Doors",
amperage,
substring(regexp_replace(amperage, ',', ''), '(?<=([0-9]+\-)?)([0-9]+)\s?(?=A?)')::numeric AS "Amperage",
voltage AS "Voltage",
--Terms
listing_expiration_date,
minimum_lease_term,
maximum_lease_term,
rate_type_desc,
maximum_asking_rate_monthly,
minimum_asking_rate_monthly,
maximum_asking_rate_yearly,
minimum_asking_rate_yearly,
asking_price_for_sale,
tenent_improvement_allowance,
availability_type_desc,
vacant_f,
orgs."Lessor",
orgs."Listing Rep Co",
orgs."Listing Broker",
orgs."Sub Lessor",
orgs."Sub Lessor Rep Co",
orgs."Sub Lessor Broker"
FROM master_dataview.extract_property_space_availability
/* Rep/Broker information
- Concatenate organizations/broker names
*/
LEFT JOIN (
SELECT property_space_availability_skey,
STRING_AGG(DISTINCT CASE party_organization_role_type_desc WHEN 'Lessor' THEN party_organization_name ELSE null END, ' / ') AS "Lessor",
STRING_AGG(DISTINCT CASE party_organization_role_type_desc WHEN 'Sub Lessor' THEN party_organization_name ELSE null END, ' / ') AS "Sub Lessor",
STRING_AGG(DISTINCT CASE party_organization_role_type_desc WHEN 'Listing Representative' THEN party_organization_name ELSE null END, ' / ') AS "Listing Rep Co",
STRING_AGG(DISTINCT CASE party_individual_role_type_desc WHEN 'Listing Representative' THEN party_individual_name ELSE null END, ' / ') AS "Listing Broker",
STRING_AGG(DISTINCT CASE party_organization_role_type_desc WHEN 'Sub lease Representative' THEN party_organization_name ELSE null END, ' / ') AS "Sub Lessor Rep Co",
STRING_AGG(DISTINCT CASE party_individual_role_type_desc WHEN 'Sub lease Representative' THEN party_individual_name ELSE null END, ' / ') AS "Sub Lessor Broker"
FROM master_dataview.extract_property_space_availability
GROUP BY property_space_availability_skey) AS orgs
USING (property_space_availability_skey)
WHERE property_division_desc = 'Pacific-Southwest'
AND property_market_desc IN ('Los Angeles', 'San Diego', 'Orange County', 'Phoenix', 'Ventura', 'Hawaii', 'Inland Empire', 'Tucson')
AND property_usage_type_desc = 'Industrial'
AND space_availability_status_desc = 'Active'
AND statistical_f = 'Y'
AND miq_record_hide_f!='Y'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This most commonly occurs when the data type/precision of any column has changed after the first successful extract. Go through each column and make sure the the data type matches what you have in the tableau workbook.

Comment: Wondering why would the data type change? Is there a way I can include a loop to avoid any columns from changing their data type?

Comment: Changes can be as simple as data type changed from number to date or something to that end in the workbook.

Comment: You were right, there was just one column that for some reason had to be converted to a string. Thanks!

Comment: Glad that I was able to help!